# How can I convert a dictionary into a comma separated .txt file while maintaining the key:value pair? Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I need to write in a .txt file in comma separated value format. I have tried

```
mydict = {'first': ['1','2','3'], 'second': ['2','3','4'], 'third': ['3','4','5']}
f = open("doc.txt","w")
for key, values in mydict:
    f.write(','.format(key, values)+"\n")
f.close()
```

But it does not work , as the values are too many. 
I have also tried to create two comma separated lists for keys and values, using .join, but I need the values to be mapped to the keys, as you would have in a CSV file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what would be your desired result?

Comment: This ```for key, values in mydict:``` should be ```for key, values in mydict.items():```.

Comment: same result as a csv file, with rows and columns, so that if I have to analyse the results from the txt file, the values are still linked to the keys. Is it possible to do it without importing packages?

Comment: This is the error message I get " for key, value in mydict.values():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: @Mary _same result as a csv file_ doesn't tell us much, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mary I forgot to mention that this isn't guaranteed to maintain the _key:value_ pair! For example, what happens if one of the keys is "it's me, a key"? I'm also confused by the statement _values to be mapped to the keys, as you would have in a CSV file._ Can you specify, first, for what purpose you're writing these to file, and second, what the role of CSV is in all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you're iterating through the dictionary, you should be using `mydict.items()`.

As for as formatting the rows for the csv, you need to join the values into a string, then format the new line:

```py
my_dict = {'first': ['1', '2', '3'], 'second': ['2', '3', '4'], 'third': ['3', '4', '5']}
with open('doc.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, values in my_dict.items():
        f.write(f"{key},{','.join(values)}\n")
```

This will produce a text file with the following output:

```
second,2,3,4
third,3,4,5
first,1,2,3
```

Note that the output will not be ordered `first`, `second`, `third`, because dictionaries do not return the keys in the order you entered them.

Comment: Can I ask you what does "%s,%s\n' %" do?

Comment: @Ally In the string `'%s,%s\n'` there are two `%s` values. When python sees the `%` following the string, it matches up each of those two `%s` with a value in the following `list` or `tuple` (in this case `key` and `','.join(values)`).

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through the dictionary’s keys and values, you have to call the dict.items() method in your for loop. This will convert a key-value pair into a tuple.